# an identity involving products of ratios of gamma

Tags: gamma-function, infinite-product

I found the following identity from a special functions book while I have no idea proving it.

Suppose $\sum_{m=1}^k(a_m-b_m)=0$,
$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(n-a_1)\cdots(n-a_k)}{(n-b_1)\cdots(n-b_k)}=\prod_{m=1}^k\frac{\Gamma(1-b_m)}{\Gamma(1-a_m)},$$
where $\Gamma(z)$ is the gamma function.

Any tips regarding how to derive this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Immediately follows from [infinite product representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Euler's_definition_as_an_infinite_product) of $\Gamma$, say $$\Gamma(1-z)=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1+1/n)^{-z}}{1-z/n}.$$

Comment: Thanks for this smart way. However, the product only works for z is not a positive integer. So, how to overcome this?

Comment: This also pertains to the identity being proven. Thus there's really nothing to overcome.